SwiftUI draw path by gesture when scale changed issue
I have an example of using gestures to draw on pictures.
However, after zooming in on the picture, the position drawn by the gesture cannot correspond to the actual position on the screen.
Or is there any other way to reach the hand-painted layer and merge it into the picture?
Are there any similar examples or solutions?
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var lines: [[CGPoint]] = [[]]
    @State private var currentLineWidth: CGFloat = 5.0
    @State private var drawnImage: UIImage = .init()
    @State private var zoomScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State private var lastZoomScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State private var imageOffset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var lastImageOffset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var drawing: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                    Image(uiImage: drawnImage)
                        .resizable()
                        .background(Color.gray)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .scaleEffect(zoomScale)
                        .offset(x: imageOffset.width, y: imageOffset.height)
                        .gesture(
                            MagnificationGesture()
                                .onChanged { value in
                                    if lastZoomScale * value >= 1 && lastZoomScale * value <= 2  {
                                        zoomScale = lastZoomScale * value
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                                .onEnded { value in
                                    lastZoomScale = zoomScale
                                    
                                }
                                .simultaneously(with:
                                    DragGesture()
                                        .onChanged { value in
                                            imageOffset = CGSize(width: lastImageOffset.width + value.translation.width, height: lastImageOffset.height + value.translation.height)
                                        }
                                        .onEnded { value in
                                            lastImageOffset = imageOffset
                                        }
                                )
                        )
                        

                if (drawing) {
                    Canvas { context, size in
                        for line in lines {
                            var path = Path()
                            guard let firstPoint = line.first else { continue }
                            path.move(to: adjustedPoint(firstPoint))

                            for point in line.dropFirst() {
                                path.addLine(to: point)
                            }
                            context.stroke(path, with: .color(.blue), lineWidth: currentLineWidth)
                        }
                    }
                    .background(Color.init(white: 1, opacity: 0.5))
                    .scaleEffect(zoomScale)
                    .offset(x: imageOffset.width, y: imageOffset.height)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                            .onChanged { value in

                                let newPoint = CGPoint(
                                    x: (value.location.x / zoomScale) - (imageOffset.width  / zoomScale) ,
                                    y: (value.location.y / zoomScale) - (imageOffset.height / zoomScale)
                                )

                                lines[lines.count - 1].append(newPoint)
                            }
                            .onEnded { value in
                                lines.append([])
                            }
                    )
                }

            }
            .frame(maxWidth: self.drawnImage.size.width * zoomScale, maxHeight: self.drawnImage.size.height * zoomScale)
            .border(Color.black, width: 5)

            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    lines = [[]]
                }) {
                    Text("Clear")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    drawing.toggle()
                    
                    if(!drawing){
                        print("Moving")

                        mergeDrawingWithImage(image: self.drawnImage)
                    }else{
                        print("Drawing")

                    }
                    
                }) {
                    if (drawing) {
                        Text("Drawing")
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.orange)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                    } else {
                        Text("Moving")
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.orange)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                    }

                }

                Button(action:{
                    mergeDrawingWithImage(image: self.drawnImage)
                }) {
                    Text("Save Drawing")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                }
                
                Slider(value: $currentLineWidth, in: 1...10, step: 1) {
                    Text("Line Width")
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.drawnImage = UIImage(named: "background")!

        })
    }
    
    private func adjustedPoint(_ point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(
            x: point.x,
            y: point.y
        )
    }
    
    func mergeDrawingWithImage(image: UIImage) {

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: image.size)
        let mergedImage = renderer.image { context in
            // Draw the original image
            image.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)

            // Draw the lines on top of the original image
            let strokeColor = UIColor.blue
            context.cgContext.setStrokeColor(strokeColor.cgColor)
            context.cgContext.setLineWidth(currentLineWidth)
            context.cgContext.setLineCap(.round)

            for line in lines {
                guard let firstPoint = line.first else { continue }
                context.cgContext.beginPath()
                context.cgContext.move(to: firstPoint)
                for point in line.dropFirst() {
                    context.cgContext.addLine(to: point)
                }
                context.cgContext.strokePath()
            }
        }

        self.drawnImage = mergedImage
        
        clear()
    }
    
    func clear() {
        lines = [[]]
    }
}

Try to add scale parameter, but still incorrect.
